# ITMS-90683: Missing purpose string in Info.plist without using those Apis

Tags: ios, reactjs, native

ITMS-90683: Missing purpose string in Info.plist - Your app’s code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data, or the app has one or more entitlements that permit such access. The Info.plist file for the “olivier.app” bundle should contain a NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. If your app supports multiple locales, you’re now required to provide a purpose string value in the Info.plist file in addition to a valid localized string across each of your app’s localization folders. If you’re using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/requesting_access_to_protected_resources.

Though you are not required to fix the following issues, we wanted to make you aware of them:

ITMS-90725: SDK Version Issue - This app was built with the iOS 15.5 SDK. Starting April 2023, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 16.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 14.1 or later.

ITMS-90683: Missing purpose string in Info.plist - Your app’s code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data, or the app has one or more entitlements that permit such access. The Info.plist file for the “olivier.app” bundle should contain a NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. If your app supports multiple locales, you’re now required to provide a purpose string value in the Info.plist file in addition to a valid localized string across each of your app’s localization folders. If you’re using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/requesting_access_to_protected_resources.

ITMS-90683: Missing purpose string in Info.plist - Your app’s code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data, or the app has one or more entitlements that permit such access. The Info.plist file for the “olivier.app” bundle should contain a NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. If your app supports multiple locales, you’re now required to provide a purpose string value in the Info.plist file in addition to a valid localized string across each of your app’s localization folders. If you’re using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/requesting_access_to_protected_resources.

But I'm not using those permissions (maybe in before but now I don't)

My info.plist:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN2BV.png)

I generate new js bundle with this command  bellow but without result

react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In their feedback, regarding the “purpose” strings, they say:

> If you’re using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required.

So, review your libraries and make sure you don’t have any lingering ones that you are no longer using. And if all of the libraries are being used, figure out (or make some reasonable assumption) why they might have that API call and add an appropriate purpose/usage string. But you can’t have a library that might be using these API without an appropriate usage string in your `Info` plist/settings.

Note, while you are adding purpose strings, if you never make a library/API call that triggers the associated permission, then that string will likely never be shown in the UI. But you must still add that purpose string in your `Info` plist/settings. It protects you in case there is some edge case with that third party library that might trigger the permission popup and lets Apple know that you are aware what your libraries might do with user data.

---

Regarding the SDK version:

> ITMS-90725: SDK Version Issue - This app was built with the iOS 15.5 SDK. Starting April 2023, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 16.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 14.1 or later.

You might as well make sure that you have a contemporary version of Xcode and set the project’s base SDK version in your project to 16.1 or later. April is right around the corner, so you are going to have to do this soon, anyway. And, assuming you are using an up-to-date version of Xcode, this is generally a pretty simple setting to fix.

Comment: yes you are right I have some libraries I don't use them anymore as : - "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^3.0.1" - "react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.3" -